# How to hide element using "this"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pardon my stupidity but can someone please explain to me how can I hide element using `this` keyword?
For example this is working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    if($('.someclass').length==1){
        $('.someclass').hide();
    }  
});
```

But this is a no go for me:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    if($('.someclass').length==1){
        $(this).hide();
    }  
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: this is a keyword to refer the object were you're on. You can only use "this" to refer to an element if you're coding inside that element body/events.

Comment: You must have thought that "this" is cool. Don't use something just for the sake of using it.

Comment: Actually i do think that "this" is cool because it allows me to not repeating classes over and over again:=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to use `this` (in which case, see other answers) or you just seek to avoid selector duplication? What about this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var elem = $('.someclass');
  if(elem.length == 1){
    elem.hide();
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, you can only reference 'this' when the '.someclass' object is the calling object. You can see this inside events and most callback related things in jQuery.

ie.:

```
$('.someclass').each(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});

$('.someclass').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

However by doing this you are wrapping the object, and any matching objects, twice.

The best way to do what your code represents is to remove the if statement completely as querying the length of the jQuery object is not actually required here. jQuery does not execute functions on result sets that are empty so a simple...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.someclass').hide();
});
```

...is all that is required.

Comment: Nice explanation THX however my element will contain children that is why i am using an if statment "upvoted your answer" :=)

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to avoid duplications then it should be as simple as:

```
$(function() {
    $('.someclass').hide();
});
```

You don't need to check `length` at all. jQuery is smart enough not to do anything if there is  no elements.

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't need to use `this` for such purpose - consider the following example on the other hand:

```
$('.someClass').each(function(){

    // maybe some logic here
    $(this).hide();

});
```

In this case, `this` refers to the current DOM element in each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('.someclass').each(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable `this` must be in an event handler, `each` method or something like this. For example:

```
$('.someclass').each(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```